# Test if event was not triggered on element with Jasmine spy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jquery-events, jasmine-jquery

I am covering this part of system with tests at the moment, I have events chained in a way that stopping propagation on first must cancel second event from firing.

```
$.fn.extend({
        OnTheMoveBCTrigger: function (name, options) {
            if (!(this[0] instanceof OnTheMove_BusinessComponent)) {
                throw ('is not an instance of OnTheMove_BusinessComponent');
            } else {
                var event = $.Event(name);
                var promise = $(this).OnTheMoveTrigger(event, options);
                if (!event.isPropagationStopped()) {
                    $(onTheMove.PageDataRoles).OnTheMoveTrigger(name, options);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I figured how to check that second event was fired with jasmine-jquery `spyOnEvent`

```
    it("OnTheMoveBCTrigger chain fires event on onTheMove.PageDataRoles", function () {
        var spy = spyOnEvent(onTheMove.PageDataRoles, 'event2');
        $(window.bc).OnTheMoveBCTrigger("event2");
        expect('event2').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(onTheMove.PageDataRoles);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });
```

but now I need to test the case where propagation is being stopped and second event is not being fired.
**How to check if event has not been fired?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `not` property on Jasmine `expect` that allows to invert the check.
Code below worked for me.

```
    it("OnTheMoveBCTrigger does NOT chain fire event on onTheMove.PageDataRoles, if propogation is stopped on BC event.", function () {
        var spy = spyOnEvent(onTheMove.PageDataRoles, 'event3');
        $(window.bc).on("event3", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(window.bc).OnTheMoveBCTrigger("event3");
        expect('event3').not.toHaveBeenTriggeredOn(onTheMove.PageDataRoles);
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });
```